# how to calculate time difference between two dates? - MySql

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
code    id                  date               time difference   
AiK4JJ  kcy2000ok   2012-01-31 17:25:41         13    
unBG1D  gktoql      2012-01-31 17:25:35          3    
vzqeWU  gktoql      2012-01-31 17:25:32          4    
vvkOSd  judyssi     2012-01-31 17:25:32          8    
uwhbGt  kcy2000ok   2012-01-31 17:25:28 ?    
unBG1D  gktoql      2012-01-31 17:25:27         ?    
vvkOSd  judyssi     2012-01-31 17:25:24         ?
```

I want to calculate the time difference in seconds between recent date and previous date based on id.

If you look at kcy2000ok, time difference is 13 seconds for last row.

time difference for gktoql is 3 seconds for last row.

I need to make a query that calculate time difference based on id.

Can you help me to build MySql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as difference FROM <your-table-name>`

**Addendum:**
Your question was a little bit hard to understand until you editied it. So to make this clear: If you want to calculate the minimum difference grouped by id, you can do:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)) as difference
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account, that only time differences between rows with the same `id` are wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean find the number of seconds since the most recent record for each user:

```
SELECT id, min(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time))
GROUP BY id
```

Or to get the most recent record for each user:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY `date` desc) x
GROUP BY id
```